# Can I get clamav-daemon to run without first updating with freshclam?

Tags: clamav

It's painfully slow to run freshclam, but clamav-daemon won't start without it:

```
$ sudo service clamav-daemon start
* Clamav signatures not found in /var/lib/clamav
* Please retrieve them using freshclam
* Then run '/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon start'
```

Can I get clamav-daemon to ignore it so each server don't have to run a 10-30 minute update on first deploy?

Answer (score 1):

You should always use fresh signatures.To speed-up the startup I would use a caching proxy like `squid`.

Comment: The point is that even if I temporarily put up squid downloading virus definitions is going to take longer than all the provisioning I have to do across all the servers. I have a self updating daemon already, i can also download definitions async on first install. I just want the scanning daemon to be running.

Answer (score 0):

It happens every time, yes. After that sequence during the install, do:

```
freshclam
```

Once the downloads are complete, do:

```
/etc/init.d/clamav-daemon start
```

then you can restart your clamav service.